# Rolling a Ball Using THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've been working on this little pool game in WebGL using THREE.JS.

Now I have a problem with rolling a ball from a position, say `Vector3(0, 0, 0)` to another position `Vector3(10, 50, 200)`. The movement isn't a problem, however I just can't work out the rotation. Here's how i do it, or, trying to:

First I get the distance:

```
var movement = new THREE.Vector3();
movement.subVectors(to, from);
var distance = movement.length();
```

Next I calculate the angle

```
var angle = (distance / (radius * 2 * Math.PI));
```

After that, things get a little bit confusing, I do not know what methods to use to rotate the actual object - I've tried quaternions:

```
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(movement.normalize(), angle);
mesh.rotation.setEulerFromQuaternion(quaternion);
```

Does anyone know  how to achieve this rotation?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does this example help? https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/801daaa005c373eab6847741bd3f497a

Comment: I solved this on my own and forgot to answer it myself, but yes, this would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
mesh.rotation.set(along_x, along_y, along_z);
mesh.rotation.z += 0.1;
```

You could use `applyTransformation` on the mesh, and after that you should have your lookAt vector pointing to `to` vector, and then applying simple animated rotation around x-axis (since lookAt vector = z-axis of the object).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not really know what you mean, how exactly would I align the sphere so that the z direction would point to the target?